# Property "BankMaster.swift_code" is not defined

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2, cexception

I am having issues rendering a modal when i click on add new button in yii with these error

**CException**

Property "BankMaster.swift_code" is not defined

This the view file (**BankMaster/_form.php**)

```
 <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model, 'swift_code', array('labelOptions' => array('class' => 'col-md-8 bank-master-settings-cls'), 'class' => 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12', 'maxlength' => 100)); ?>
```

**swift_code** is the changes i made.

This the Model file (**BankMaster.php**)

```
public function rules() {
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('full_name, short_name,iban_no,branch,payroll_status', 'required'),
        array('full_name, address, email,swift_code', 'safe'),
        array('opening_balance', 'numerical'),
        array('ledger_code', 'uniqueCode'),
        array('telephone,account_no, company_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
        array('short_name,ledger_code', 'length', 'max' => 100),
        array('full_name, email', 'length', 'max' => 100),
        array('email', 'email'),
        array('short_name', 'uniqueInLedger'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, short_name,account_no,iban_no,opening_balance,op_balance_dc,branch_type,branch, full_name, address, telephone, email, payroll_status, is_default', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
    );
}
```

**swift_code** is the changes i made too.

Then i added a column in **erp_bank_master** table

SOLUTION: "wp_105578" was the right database instead of "wpexp_dev"

[image]

[image]

Comment: may be issue with `cache`. Clear your cache.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Thanks but still give same error. How do you mean clear your cache?

Comment: if you are using FileCache , please remove directory /runtime/cache/*

Comment: Try solution by @Mahsa

Comment: @all THE SOLUTION: "wp_105578" was the right database instead of "wpexp_dev" thanks for your support.